# Docker Swarm automatically tries and fails to pull images from GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-swarm

I'm using Docker Swarm for container orchestration on a unbuntu server and for the past few months I have been running into a weird problem. To preface: I didn't set up the system, just took it over. This was never an issue before but I also didn't change anything about the configuration.

Every 2 months or so it seems like Docker deletes and tries to update all images from master branches (and ONLY master branches). However, the daemon fails to pull from the GitLab repos which causes the containers to fail. This is the error message it keeps logging:

```
dockerd[1302]: time="2023-05-22T10:48:20.216948993+02:00" level=error msg="pulling image failed" 
error="Get [URL]/master/manifests/[…]: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or 
token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead 
of a password. module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=[ID] service.id=[ID] task.id=[ID]
```

This seems like an obvious error message, however:

- I am using a personal access token to pull images (which is still valid), configured under `/root/.docker/config.json`
- We don't use 2FA on GitLab
- when I manually pull images I don't run into any authorization issues
- the `--with-registry-auth` flag is not a solution to this problem, I already use it to deploy all stacks, so unless I configured the auth credentials in the wrong place this is not the cause.

Docker tries to log into my GitLab account specifically although several people use the machine and docker swarm.

Manually pulling the images and reploying the stack fixes the issues acutely but I'd like to know what is causing it and prevent it in the future.

So I have several questions:

- Why does docker remove and pull just the master images or do the pulls only fail for the master images?
- Is when and how Docker Swarm updates images configured anywhere explicitly?
- Is the config.json file the correct place for auth config? or should it belong to my user?

Has anyone run into a similar problem or has an idea whats going on?